# Use system sounds of Android in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

First of all thanks for reading my question. The question is: how can I play system default Android sounds in my Unity game? For example when I click a button I want to hear the same sound when I click the home button. I hope you can help me!

Thanks in advance,
Máté